# Create a "slot machine" with dynamic height children

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am working on a layout that is similar in nature to a slot machine. Each of its children will be text, and the layout is responsive (so at different resolutions, the children's text may or may not wrap to multiple lines, thus changing the height).

The layout will have a visible "viewport" of 3 items at a time. So that the "viewport" does not shift around, all children need to have the same height. This got me thinking of 2 different routes, but I can't make either work.

1. Use display: flex. With a column layout, you can have them all stack. The problem with this is, I don't think you can make all children have the same height unless you specify a calculated height on the flex container (thus, you'd have to use js to calculate the max height of all the flex children)
2. Use display: grid. Out of the box you can make all children have equal height with grid. The problem is, how do hide the overflow guaranteeing you are only showing 3 at a time in the "viewport" for the slot machine?

This layout may not be possible without js calculations, but because of the fact that it has to be completely responsive, I don't want to have to redo the calculations on every window resize. Can anyone think of a way to do this using pure css?

I made a fiddle to show a bare-bones implementation. The "viewport" is the red box, and each item is in the blue box. In the real world, I would be hiding everything outside of the red box and would not want to have to specifically set height on any container.

```js
var scroll = document.getElementById('scroll');
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

scroll.addEventListener('click', function() {
  wrapper.classList.toggle('scrolled');
});
```

```css
.example {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  height: 90px;
  width: 300px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  z-index:1;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
}

.wrapper.scrolled {
  transform: translateY(-300px);
}

.inner {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 30px;
}

.buttons {
  margin-right: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button id="scroll">Scroll</button>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
      <div class="inner">Some text</div>
      <div class="inner">Some text</div>
      <div class="inner">Some text</div>
      <div class="inner">Some text</div>
      <div class="inner">Some text</div>
      <div class="inner">Some text</div>
      <div class="inner">Some text</div>
      <div class="inner">Some text</div>
      <div class="inner">Some text</div>
      <div class="inner">Some text</div>
      <div class="inner">Some text</div>
      <div class="inner">Some text</div>
      <div class="inner">Some text</div>
      <div class="inner">Some text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you not use percents for the container? Like width: 100%;

Comment: How would you use a percent for the container?

Comment: Instead of pixels use percents as it makes the app more responsive

Comment: Setting a height in percentage on the .container will do nothing. That would be a percentage of its parent's height. It needs to have its height determined by 3 of its children. I'm not sure you read my question or looked at my example...

Comment: I just re-read it and think I get what your asking for- my idea is you could set each of the children’s with special id’s. When you click the button it generates a random number within the amount of children. With that random number figure out 2 next to the one children and with Js, make the extra children not in use have a class that displays: none;

Comment: There would be 0 animation with that, it would immediately go from the start state to the end state with no scroll animation like I have. Also,, if all 3 that were initially shown were 1 line in height and the next 3 were all 2 lines in height, this would essentially double the bounding container after this state change. This will not work.

Comment: You can always make a animation for in between clicking the button and showing final result. For the double line thing, I would make the bounding container already the size of having 2 lines. And if they go over 2 lines then just don’t show the extra “thinking if there names” then if only one line is used, the other can be blank.

Comment: Two lines was arbitrary. It could span 4, 5, who knows. This is not a solution. This doesn't answer my original question.

Comment: Is support for Microcrap browsers essential?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. Has to go back to IE10. What did you have in mind?

Comment: _"I don't want to have to redo the calculations on every window resize."_, how often do you think a normal user resize their browser window? ... Users might tilt their tablet/phone/PC, so you need a _resize function_ if you want it to look good, so do you still not want to use a resize event?

Comment: A normal user wouldn't do it too often, I was just hoping there was some css alternative. If I can't find a pure css way to do it, I'll rely on the window resize

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I think I get what you're going for here and designed a "slot machine" mechanic that scales its inner and outer objects using vh.

So the container object would have something like...

```
.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 90vh;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    z-index:1;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

...and the inner object would have something like...

```
.inner {
    outline: 1px solid blue;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 30vh;
}
```

I also adjusted the Javascript scrolling to base the amount scrolled off of what object is being scrolled to. This can be automated with something like a timer instead of the button:

```
var scroll = document.getElementById('scroll');
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var innerArray = document.getElementsByClassName('inner');

var innerNum = 1; // Start at the second element
scroll.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (innerNum == innerArray.length-2) { // Check to see if the last item has been scrolled to
    innerNum = 0; // Scroll back to the first item if it has
  }
  //wrapper.classList.toggle('scrolled');
  innerArray[innerNum].scrollIntoView({ 
    behavior: 'smooth' 
  });
  innerNum++;
});
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/ChaseIngebritson/pen/xPPRPp) is the Codepen that demonstrates the example. I can clarify the code further if you would like me to. My apologies if I was way off the ball on what you were going for!

Comment: You weren't way off and I understand what you did, however this only masks the underlying issue. 1. There are a bunch of other things on the screen, so using vh is not really an option. 2. What if 30vh isn't tall enough when someone is doing this on a mobile phone in landscape mode?